# Android StudioでFacebook SDKをインポート

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook, gradle

```
エラー :(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.
```

Android Studio で Import Module で Facebook SDK をインポートしたら、 Gradle の同期で上記のエラーが出てしまいました。

原因が不明です。

プロジェクト構成も設定済みです。

- Android Studio　ver.1.0.2
- Facebook SDK 3.21.1

よろしくお願いします。

追記

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

project.group = 'com.facebook.android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.2.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

def isSnapshot = version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')
def ossrhUsername = hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : ""
def ossrhPassword = hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : ""

task setVersion {
    // The version will be derived from source
    project.version = null
    def sdkVersionFile = file('src/com/facebook/FacebookSdkVersion.java')
    sdkVersionFile.eachLine{
        def matcher = (it =~ /(?:.*BUILD = \")(.*)(?:\".*)/)
        if (matcher.matches()) {
          project.version = matcher[0][1]
          return
        }
    }
    if (project.version.is('unspecified')) {
      throw new GradleScriptException('Version could not be found.', null)
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

        repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
            authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
        }

        snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
            authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
        }

        pom.project {
            name 'Facebook-Android-SDK'
            artifactId = 'facebook-android-sdk'
            packaging 'aar'
            description 'Facebook Android SDK'
            url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'

            scm {
                connection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'
            }

            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/LICENSE.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }

            developers {
                developer {
                    id 'facebook'
                    name 'Facebook'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

uploadArchives.dependsOn(setVersion)

signing {
    required { !isSnapshot && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
    sign configurations.archives
}

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}

afterEvaluate {
    androidJavadocs.classpath += project.android.libraryVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.classpath
}

setting Gradle
include ':aplname', ':Facebook'
```

Comment: 手元(Mac OS X 10.9.5)で適当なプロジェクトを作って、ご指定のバージョンの Facebook SDK のモジュールをインポートしてみましたが、問題は再現しませんでした。build.gradle や settings.gradle も共有してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: mkkitaro さん、 hkurokawa の言われるように、質問を編集して Gradle の設定ファイルを張っていただけますか？ それでスムーズに解決につなげられると思います。

Comment: hkurokawaさん、Yamamotoさん
コメントありがとうございます。
追記情報更新しました。

Comment: @mkkitaro スペース4個で字下げしてコードを見やすく整形して頂ければと思います。 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 2):

見たところ、添付いただいた build.gradle は、アプリの build.gradle ではなく、Facebook モジュールの build.gradle のような気がするのですが、どこの build.gradle でしょうか?

参考までに、私が試したときの手順を以下に示しますね。長いので、コメントではなく、回答の方を使わせてもらいます。問題があったらお知らせください。

1. **Start a new Android Studio Project** で新規にプロジェクトを開始
2. 左上のメニューから **File** > **Import Module** を選択し、解凍した Facebook SDK ディレクトリ直下の **facebook** フォルダを指定(例: `/Users/hiroshi/Downloads/android/facebook/facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1/facebook`)
3. `Error:(15, 0) Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' on project ':facebook'.`というビルドエラーで出たので、以下をプロジェクト直下の gradle.properties に追記 (これが正しい方法か分かりませんが、とりあえず本筋の問題とは関係ないので、これで回避しました)

   ```
   ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=21
   ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=21.1.1
   ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=21
   ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=14
   ```
4. この時点でフォルダ構成は以下のようになっています

   ```
   [~/workspaces/MyApplication]% tree -L 2
    .
    ├── MyApplication.iml
    ├── app
    │   ├── app.iml
    │   ├── build
    │   ├── build.gradle
    │   ├── libs
    │   ├── proguard-rules.pro
    │   └── src
    ├── build.gradle
    ├── facebook
    │   ├── AndroidManifest.xml
    │   ├── build.gradle
    │   ├── build.xml
    │   ├── libs
    │   ├── project.properties
    │   ├── res
    │   └── src
    ├── gradle
    │   └── wrapper
    ├── gradle.properties
    ├── gradlew
    ├── gradlew.bat
    ├── local.properties
    └── settings.gradle
   ```

   また、MyApplication/app/build.gradle、MyApplication/build.gradle、MyApplication/settings.gradle は以下のようになっています。https://gist.github.com/hkurokawa/c75ada3f861941366b2c

この状態で、ビルドが通るはずです。ご参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: 再度プロジェクトを作り直してみたら、hkurokawaさんと同じ状態になりました。
同じようにバージョンを記載したら解決しました。 みなさん、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

ググったらそれっぽい回答が出てきました。

一例
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204436/error1-0-plugin-with-id-android-not-found

build.gradleの中でgradleのバージョンを指定している箇所が'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'などなっていたら'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'にして、同期取れば直るらしいです。理由は分かりませんが。
build.gradleの内容に不安があれば、適当な名前でプロジェクト作れば勝手に1.0.0でいい感じにファイルが作られるはず。

Comment: user3009331さん
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'にはなっております。
すみません。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @mkkitaro 浅薄な知識で回答してしまい、すみません…